# Running a shell script after up -d docker

Tags: docker

I've managed to find a solution to an issue coming up with multiple docker containers not quite working with each other properly.

Currently the only solution I've found has been running a series of commands manually after running my docker-compose. However, I need this to be able to automatically run after a client does a variety of things with the containers, such as update or full deploy.

Is there a way I can get a shell script to run once the containers are fully loaded?

Comment: You can in fact run a shell script on the host after you run `docker-compose up -d`; you might need a helper like the `wait-for-it.sh` tool to wait for the containers to _actually_ be up.  Is there a specific problem you're encountering doing this?

Comment: I'm using tvial and need to restart amavis, dovecot, postfix and rsyslog to get it to interact with my mail API properly. it only seems to affect anything when I manually restart the services after the compose.

Comment: ...on your host?  That's a kind of unusual setup, but you should be able to run `docker-compose up -d && service restart things` just fine.

Comment: Define "fully loaded", then think about this more than once. How would Docker know what it means to be "fully loaded". It's your responsibility, have your own entrypoint and do whatever you need to do, anytime you need it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually got this sorted last night and will try to explain it as much as possible cuz I was asking on other sites and turns out there was an issue with the container.

So inside the start-mailserver.sh script that tvial uses, one of the last lines is a hanging log command:

```
tail -fn 0 /var/log/mail/mail.log
```

This was causing any adjustments I made to services in the run.sh or dockerfile to not go through. What I've had to do is add a few lines to the end of my run.sh script to work around it:

```
usr/local/bin/start-mailserver.sh &

sleep 10

/xxxxx/ServerFix.sh

tail -fn 0 /var/log/mail/mail.log
```

And then ServerFix is various service restarts I needed to run.